# How can I get exhaust list of functions available to grad_fn for backward() function in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, automatic-differentiation

Tensors which can calculate gradient will have grad_fn=AddBackward0 or MulBackward0 or SubBackward0.

Is there any Python command that can list all these "xxxBackward0" methods and their respective forward and backward formulas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a singular python command, but you can check out the methods for [torch.Tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html).

Basically all tensor operations that aren't "hard" (ie like argsort, logical operators) have a backward method implemented.